Where are the community wikis?
I'm new here but got the first privilege "edit community wiki".
Great, but I don't recognize any link to it.
I guess, having a look there would save me from asking a lot of duplicate questions.
(I do have a severe case of banner-blindness, so maybe it is advertised everywhere and I just don't recognize it.)

"community wiki" is a bit of a confusing term. It doesn't refer to a wiki such as a collection of collaboratively-editable pages; the entire Stack Exchange network is that itself - all posts are editable by other users, and such edits are encouraged.
Instead, community wiki refers to a special type of post. Community wiki posts can be either questions or answers, although any answers to a community wiki question have to be community wiki as well.
Community wiki posts do not earn anybody reputation. The reputation threshold for editing community wiki posts without peer review is 100 rep instead of 1000 (2000 on some sites).
When writing a post, you have a little checkbox that you can tick to mark the post as community wiki:

Once you've made a post community wiki, that can't be undone without moderator assistance.
Community wiki is in theory used for posts that are meant to be maintained and regularly updated by the community. In practice, it's hardly used these days outside of meta sites (particularly Meta.SE, the meta site for the entire Stack Exchange network). AI.SE only has 32 total posts marked as community wiki. It's a bit of a legacy feature that fell out of popular use.
